# MapBox ESRI Data Layer

Tags: json, gis, spatial, mapbox, esri

I have a mapbox, and want to display a layer of esri data onto it. The data I'm getting is being pulled in from this json file:

https://gis.usps.com/arcgis/rest/services/EDDM/selectZIP/GPServer/routes/execute?f=json&env%3AoutSR=102100&ZIP=93003&Rte_Box=R&UserName=EDDM

The data['results'][0]['value']['features'] array looks something like this:

> [{'attributes': {'key':'value'}},{'geometry':{'paths':[[-13273770,4064608],[-13273762,4064613],....]}},
>   {'attributes': {'key':'value'}},{'geometry':{'paths':[[-13273770,4064608],[-13273762,4064613],....]}},
>   {'attributes': {'key':'value'}},{'geometry':{'paths':[[-13273770,4064608],[-13273762,4064613],....]}}}]

My question is about the geometry array. The data there is not Lat/Lng values (which I was hoping for), so I'm not sure how to add these to my map. I'm new to GIS, and the research I've done so far points to SpatialReferences. Any help is obviously much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MapBox seems to only accept Latitude and Longitude coordinates (from what I can tell at least).  The coordinates you have in your file come from ESRI 102100 (3857) projection system - the clue is near the beginning of your file:

*"spatialReference":{"wkid":102100,"latestWkid":3857}..."*

Normally, you'd have to convert this yourself, a good link for potential tips in the future is:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9442/arcgis-coordinate-system

On this occasion however, you can do something far easier.  Simply change the "outSR" property of your URL from **102100** to **4326** (WGS84) and let it do it for you.

https://gis.usps.com/arcgis/rest/services/EDDM/selectZIP/GPServer/routes/execute?f=json&env%3AoutSR=4326&ZIP=93003&Rte_Box=R&UserName=EDDM

Comment: Thank you so much! That was so simple, and the documentation you provided is very helpful for my future endeavors.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped Brian.