# Plotting ESRI ArcGIS data on Open Street Maps

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api, openmaptiles

I am trying to plot polylines using response data from ESRI ArcGiS. 
But instead of geo co-ordinates, what i am receive are Map Co-ordinates, which I cannot find how to implement into my maps.

I am using Mapbox Open street maps, in order to display the map as well as the polygon.

The below information is the initial part of the response.

```
"results": [
{
   "paramName": "Output_Feature_Class",
   "dataType": "GPFeatureRecordSetLayer",
   "value": {
    "displayFieldName": "",
    "geometryType": "esriGeometryPolyline",
    "spatialReference": {
     "wkid": 102100,
     "latestWkid": 3857
    },
```

While the geometry paths are.

```
 "geometry": {
   "paths": [
    [
     [
      -9983578,
      4174731
     ],
     [
      -9983584,
      4174710
     ],
     [
      -9983598,
      4174682
     ],
     [
      -9983612,
      4174652
     ],
     [
      -9983619,
      4174624
     ],
     [
      -9983591,
      4174616
     ],
     [
      -9983561,
      4174603
     ],
     [
      -9983534,
      4174581
     ],
     [
      -9983518,
      4174553
     ],
     [
      -9983513,
      4174524
     ],
     [
      -9983510,
      4174505
     ],
     [
      -9983510,
      4174463
     ],
     [
      -9983516,
      4174365
     ],
     [
      -9983519,
      4174252
     ],
     [
      -9983526,
      4174095
     ],
     [
      -9983390,
      4174093
     ]
    ],
```

I have been reading on the Mapbox documentation, and couldn't find any info on map co-ordinates. 
Can help in pointing me towards using map coordinates, and how they are to be used in plotting ploylines

I am trying to do something similar to this: https://directmail.taradel.com/step1-target.aspx

I have narrowed down to using is a Canvas overlay on top of the map, for the interim, but I am not sure on its scalability. Would appreciate your opinion here
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/canvas-source/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found an avenue I could explore.

I referred to this link which told me that I should convert the map co-ordinates to geo co-ordinates,
[MapBox ESRI Data Layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28862710/mapbox-esri-data-layer)

And the theoretic behind it is here : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9442/arcgis-coordinate-system

I will let you all know, how it goes.